# Applications discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so this is my code and i have been getting the same error over and over again. Im using v14 by the way so any help would be a great favour...

```
            {
              let embed = new EmbedBuilder(
                interaction.message.embeds[0]
              ).setColor(0x00FF00)
              .setFooter({
                
                text: client.user.tag
            });
  
              interaction.message.edit({
                embeds: [embed],
                components: [],
              });
              let ap_user = interaction.guild.members.cache.then(
                embed.footer.get(client.user.tag)
              );
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`

Comment: You don't need to use `embed.footer.get()`. `embed.footer` itself will give you everything you need. Using `embed.footer` gives you [these properties](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/EmbedFooterData)

Comment: @Caladan - given that `embed.footer` is `undefined` it would have none of those properties :p

Comment: by the way, one should pass a function to `.then` not the result of calling a function as the argument, unless calling the function returns a function, of course

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with this is that `embed.footer` returns `undefined`, not the EmbedFooterData that you'd like. I'm presuming you want `embed.data.footer`, which should return the APIEmbed Object's Footer property.

Next, `embed.data.footer.get()` does not exist. You'll need the `.text` property. Your code is rather confusing on what you're trying to do, but it **looks** like you're trying to get the `User` class from the user's tag. I don't recommend going about it that way.

Instead of going from the `tag` (`User#tag`), you should go by the `id` (`User#id`). This makes it so that if the user changes their tag, they can still be identified. Note that the `tag` is both the `User#username` property, **and** the `User#discriminator` property.

So, if you're trying to get a user based from their ID in an embed footer, it should look like this:

```js
let ap_user = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(embed.data.footer);
```

That's if you're using the `.fetch()` method, so they wouldn't have to be in the cache. You can replace `.fetch()` with `.cache.get()`, and it would have the same effect if they're cached.

A full example for your code would look like:

```js
{
  let embed = new EmbedBuilder(interaction.message.embeds[0])
    .setColor(ox00FF00)
    .setFooter({ text: client.user.id });

  interaction.message.edit({
    embeds: [embed],
    components: [],
  });

  let ap_user = interaction.guild.members.fetch(embed.data.footer.text);
```

Now, I'm not 100% certain this will work, but I am quite confident in this.
If it doesn't tell me, and I'll try to help you fix it!

Hope this helps!